# Android 6.0 : UsageEvents method 'usageStatsManger.queryEvents()' is giving count 0 (zero)

Tags: android, service, usagestatsmanager

I have created a **Service** in which I check for foreground activity using '**UsageEvents**'.

```
private void getForegroundActivity() {
        String packageName = "";
        String className = "";
        Calendar cal_begin = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_begin.set(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long _begTime = cal_begin.getTimeInMillis(); 
        long _endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

        if (usageStatsManager != null) {
            UsageEvents queryEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(_begTime, _endTime);

            if (queryEvents != null) {
                UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();

                while (queryEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
                    UsageEvents.Event eventAux = new UsageEvents.Event();
                    queryEvents.getNextEvent(eventAux);

                    if (eventAux.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                        event = eventAux;
                    }
                }

                packageName = event.getPackageName();
                className = event.getClassName();
   }
```

The above code works fine and gives proper foreground activity, but after some time(let's say 2-3 hours later), the '`queryEvents(_begTime, _endTime)`'returns '0'(zero) counts !!

Is there some other way of using `usageStatsManager.queryEvents()` in **Service** ?

Any other pointers, ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events returned by `queryEvents()` are kept by the system only for a few days. So, you might have to maintain a local database to maintain those stats locally. There is no problem in your code.

For more information about `queryEvents()` method and UsageStatsManager, checkout the below link :

[UsageStatsManager queryEvents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryEvents(long,%20long))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know queryEvents() are only for few days. How did you find about this?

Comment: @user3132107 it's mentioned in the Android documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryevents . "Query for events in the given time range. Events are only kept by the system for a few days."